# Android - Footer not displaying text

Tags: android

I've got 2 layouts (main.xml and footer_layout.xml) and am trying to append the footer_layout to my listview in main.  I can get it to display but it won't set the text when I use tvFooter.setText();

Main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/listIssues"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

footer_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/footerText"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:textSize="14dip"  
        android:textStyle="bold"  
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"> 
    </TextView>  

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.footer_layout);

    //Context context = getBaseContext();
    tvFooter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.footerText);

    //Load listview control.
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final Context context = getBaseContext();
    mListViewIssues = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listIssues);

    int DBVersion = 3;

    tvFooter.setText("DBVersion = " + String.valueOf(DBVersion));

    View footerView =  
            ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false); 

    mListViewIssues.addFooterView(footerView); 

    //add data to listview through adapter.
    mListViewIssues.setAdapter(new IssueInfoAdapter(this, creator.queryAll()));
}
```

**Note that I removed the code for 'creator' as it wasn't necessary.

This app runs and displays the data but it doesn't display "DBVersion = 3" in the footer like I want.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line:

```
tvFooter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.footerText);
```

requires that the view you are finding be "inside" your applications parent layout already.

try moving the findViewById(), and the setText() to after this line:

```
mListViewIssues.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Or better yet (and this might actually be neccessary, I am not certain it will work the other way) change it so that you are calling findViewById on one of the views in between the tvFooter and your parent view i.e. the ListView, or the plain View after you inflate it. Like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.footer_layout);

    //Context context = getBaseContext();
    tvFooter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.footerText);

    //Load listview control.
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final Context context = getBaseContext();
    mListViewIssues = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listIssues);

    int DBVersion = 3;



    View footerView =  
            ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false); 

    mListViewIssues.addFooterView(footerView); 

    tvFooter = (TextView)footerView.findViewById(R.id.footerText);
    tvFooter.setText("DBVersion = " + String.valueOf(DBVersion));


    //add data to listview through adapter.
    mListViewIssues.setAdapter(new IssueInfoAdapter(this, creator.queryAll()));
}
```

note the use of footerView.findViewById(), I think you might have better luck if you explicitly call it on the footerView object rather than just from your activity, which is essentially the same as calling it on your activities parent layout.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't set footer_layout as activity layout. The right code looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Load listview control.
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final Context context = getBaseContext();
    mListViewIssues = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listIssues);

    int DBVersion = 3;

    View footerView =((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false); 
    tvFooter = (TextView)footerView.findViewById(R.id.footerText);
    tvFooter.setText("DBVersion = " + String.valueOf(DBVersion));
    mListViewIssues.addFooterView(footerView); 

    //add data to listview through adapter.
    mListViewIssues.setAdapter(new IssueInfoAdapter(this, creator.queryAll()));
}
```